# refreshing using observables: Angular2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I'm trying to implement a functionality where the user fills in some information in the ui and when they click on a 'submit' or 'start' button the back end code starts updating information in the database (that means back end work is going on). 
  The 'status' in the ui shows if the information got updated in the database successfully or not. But, I can only see the result in the 'status' after refreshing the page. I've done some research which suggests that observables has some kind of refreshing functionality, which can be used to timely refresh some segment of the page. Can somebody point me in the right direction (maybe a tutorial, or study material) where similar kind of functionality is implemented?
Thanks

Comment: Post your code, specifically on code when the `http` request occur

Answer (score 0):

Observables are essentially streams which emit data. You can subscribe to (AKA observe) the streams.

You can create a stream of pretty much anything.

You could create a stream of button clicks. That would pipe to a downstream stream which would make requests to an endpoint.

The would pipe to another stream which would receive HTTP responses.

You would then subscribe to the final stream, to update the view each time a response is emitted from your stream (yes you can emit HTTP responses from a stream).

In Angular2, you could then for example, bind to the output of this stream.

How to do this? Not easy first time round.

I've written some hopefully easy to follow code that should help.

https://github.com/danday74/plunks

I would also recommend EggHead's tutorial on this.

https://egghead.io/courses/introduction-to-reactive-programming

Not sure how many are free but the first one certainly is and might help you.

This is free and essential to understand RXJS basics and RXJS stream diagrams.

https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754